# Is there a plugin for Eclipse that makes automatic imports smarter?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The normal Organize Imports behavior of Eclipse can make some silly suggestions. For instance, despite using `java.util.Collections` in a good number of my classes, occasionally the `edu.emory.mathcs.backport` `Collections` class will be imported instead.

I have blocked some of these silly packages in the **Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters** section of the preferences, but if there were a plugin that can figure this out automatically it would be quite helpful.

Comment: afaik, that is a good pet project to start :)

Comment: Do you have an import order set in Java -> Code Style -> Organise Imports? I don't suffer from this (unless I don't have the JDK on the path accidentally). I know this only sets the order of the imports in the source file but wonder if that's the problem?

Comment: `I don't suffer from this, either.` When you hit ctrl+shifit+O, eclipse will organize it automatically. if many imports match. a dialog will show up and let your choose the right one. it's ok

Comment: The import control idea is a good one, but that will also require manual intervention.  That and it will change the ordering of how the imports appear (if that matters to you).  The type filter solution, at least, allows the ordering and the filtering to be separate decisions.

Comment: @HenryLeu: it doesn't *always* ask to clarify ambiguous cases.  When I type `Arrays.toString(somevalue)`, and hit CTRL+SHIFT+O, it seems to always import `edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.Arrays` without asking me.

Comment: I always get the prompt from ctrl+shift+O for which package I want to import. probably you can reset the eclipse to verify whether it can work normally

Answer (score 1):

There is a Plugin (Code Recommenders Developer Tools) which should priorize the classes you prefer based on statistics. So the entries in the dialog are ordered based on their using.

It is included in eclipse kepler, but also available for older versions.

http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/

Comment: Code Recommenders does not fix this particular problem. But you may find the _Codetrails Connect Completion Tweaks_ plugin helpful: http://www.codetrails.com/blog/use-subtype-aware-completion-and-help-shape-future-code-completion